# Mathematical symbols, their pronunciations, and what they denote: Does a comprehensive ordered list exist?

Tags: notation

Often, certain symbols in mathematics denote different things in different fields.  Is there any sort of ordered list that will tell you what a certain symbol means in alphabetical order by the symbol's alias in LaTeX, perhaps with the way to pronounce it out loud?

I'm thinking of something like this [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols) but more comprehensive and usefully ordered by LaTeX alias (The one on wikipedia has very few symbols, and I am familiar with all of them already).  The problem is that when you want to find the meaning of a symbol, there is no way to search on google (because google has no support at all for searching for symbols).  Oftentimes, I'm forced to ask someone around the department what it means or how to say it out loud.

For example, I'm trying to find the meaning of the symbol $\uplus$, but I have no way of finding out what it means.  Also, for the longest time, I couldn't figure out what to call $f_!$ or $f^!$.  How should I know that they're called "f lower shriek" or "f upper shriek".

So for the question: Does any such list exist for either pronunciation, meaning, or both (aside from the one on Wikipedia that I just noted)?

Comment: Notice that such a list, indexed by LaTeX csname, would not have helped to find the pronunciation of $f_!$ and $f^!$, since these are not standard LateX symbols.  I think one learns this "organically"  with time, but it might indeed be useful to have a list somewhere.

Comment: By the way, if anyone reading this does know what $\uplus$ means, please let me know.

Comment: Multiset union?  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/228e/index.htm.  http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/mathematical_operators/images.htm

Comment: Thanks!  I think that website may just suffice as an answer, if you'd like to post it, I'll at least give it a vote up.

Comment: On a closely related note, I have often found myself wanting to use some symbol for my own purposes, but I am often held back by a worry that in so doing, I am trampling all over some established use for that symbol, thus confusing the heck out of my readers. (For example, I have no idea what symbols like $\sqcap$, $\sqcup$, $\sqsubset$, $\sqsupset$ are typically used for.) Apart from the usefulness of a comprehensive list, what do people think about co-opting symbols whose normal use is unknown to the author?

Comment: @Harald: unless you are branching into another field of mathematics, I'm sure just asking a few colleagues in your field whether they know of any alternative meanings will suffice. Then you can just be upfront about it and define those symbols (preferably all at the beginning/end of the introduction, or in an appendix). I feel that co-opting symbols is one of those things where if someone points it out to you, you buy him/her a beer and have a good laugh. It is much more important to be self-consistent and make sure the readers understand what each symbol mean when you use it.

Comment: Of course there is no such list.  Mathematics is far too diverse.  In fact, we are lucky if a book contains a list of symbols showing how they are used in just that book.


Comment: If you're so confused you don't even know how to TeX the symbol in question: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: @Harald: That is exactly the reason I want to know about it as well. @Gerald: You're attacking a straw man. For example, I just checked the back of Hartshorne, and no operations or relations are defined. They are all letters. Artin's undergraduate algebra book does this as well (those are the two that I have on hand), but neither one of them defines operations like $\boxplus$, $\boxtimes$, or $uplus$ or anything like that.

Comment: @Qiaochu: Yes, but that doesn't give you the meaning, only the name, and the comprehensive list from CTan is pretty easy to navigate through as long as you know generally what's going on.

Comment: The thing is, most symbols which are not standard, are, well, not standard. $\boxplus$ and $\boxtimes$, for example, tend to mean different things all the time.

Comment: They were standard enough to be included in unicode and LaTeX though, so I'm sure there's at least an original intended usage.

Comment: As for the f-shrieks, the problem is that you are trying to learn math by reading, but it is reasonably well-documented in the anthropology and sociology literature that math, like so much else, is best communicated in person.  Now here's the actual question: if you've never actually asked someone in person, which vowel is used in the pronunciation of "skriek"?

Comment: @Theo I dunno about anyone else, but I pronounce "shriek": /bang/

Comment: When used as a superscript and subscript in algebraic geometry and algebraic topology, it's usually pronounced "shriek", while it's pronounced as "bang" in number theory and combinatorics at least when it's used as a full-sized symbol.

Comment: Completely irrelevant, but I like Ralph Cohen's explanation of the shriek notation: it's such a surprise to find a map in that direction that it makes you shriek.

Comment: This brings up a pet peeve of mine -- the introduction of seemingly arbitrary notation in a lot of papers (for an especially egregious example look at any of Dwork's papers).  Right now I'm refereeing a very nice paper that gives me a headache every time I read it -- because the authors introduce a torrent of arbitrary notation on page 3 in a discursive form, and use that for the next 20 pages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments suggest this ...
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sm/list.htm
However, a designation like "rightwards arrow above reverse tilde operator" doesn't really answer the question here, does it?

Comment: It gives the name of the symbol, which is a partial answer.

Comment: This is actually a really good answer now that I look, and it's very likely to be accepted, since you can infer a lot of the information just from the name.  For example, this answers both my and Harald's questions.

Comment: It doesn't look like any other answers are going to be given, so I'm accepting this one.

Answer (score 6):

Relatedly, the [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) utility can help you find the LaTeX name for a symbol you can draw.

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer to your question, but as far as your problem is drawing symbols in LaTeX, you'll hardly find anything more complete than the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

Comment: Yes, I know about this.  I'm looking for something like that that also names the symbol.